# Exact reason of Why we need Delegates /

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates

Delegates an important concept in ObjC/SWIFT or any other coding language. I know that delegates are used to pass messages from one class to another class especially when we want to pass message back to a view controller from where we have just moved to some other view controller.

I was searching for more technical answer and searched a lot about this, and here is what I got what I feel might be the exact answer -

> By the rules of MVC, we need a method to return a value. Where in a
>   called instance can we go back to the class calling it? With an
>   encapsulated class we can’t. There is no way to send that revised
>   model back to the original controller without breaking encapsulation
>   or MVC. The new view controller does not know anything about the class
>   that called it. We look stuck. If we try to make a reference directly
>   to the calling controller, we may cause a reference loop that will
>   kill our memory. Simply put, we can’t send things backwards.

But the explanation says something about

> Where in a
>    called instance can we go back to the class calling it? With an
>   encapsulated class we can’t. There is no way to send that revised
>   model back to the original controller without breaking encapsulation
>   or MVC.

So exactly what does this para mean. Can any one please explain this in a more simple way taking the following code as reference -

VC2 -

```
import UIKit
protocol myDelegate : class
{
    func sendItems(name:NSString)
}
class EnterViewController: UIViewController
{
     weak var delegate: myDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextfield: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func sendData(sender: AnyObject)
    {

         delegate?.sendItems(nameTextfield.text!)
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
```

VC2

```
import UIKit

class DisplayViewController: UIViewController,myDelegate
{

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func sendItems(name: NSString) {
        self.nameLabel.text = name as String
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! EnterViewController
        if segue.identifier == "enterDetail"
        {
         destinationVC.delegate = self
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: FYI - the question has nothing to do with Objective-C or Swift. Delegation is a design pattern that is independent of any specific programming language.

Comment: @rmaddy Oh fine then,  can you please answer what I have asked in my question irrespective of discriminating between languages and with reference to the code I have provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple terms, `Delegate` is a representative of Class which works on behalf of class. If we compare in real world, delegates to foreign countries go to represent their government and have all controls and powers. Similarly, here delegates has all the control that an object of class will have and working on behalf of Class.

Now delegate in specific is an object assigned by class to notify the event. This can be acheived by `NSNotification` too. But the difference is `Delegates` can intercept the event but `NSNotification` cant.

Here in your code:

1. You have assigned **DestinationVC's** delegate to **DisplayViewController**.
2. Now **DisplayviewController** will notify all the event whatever you want to notify to Class **DestinationVC** and also intercept in between event.
3. In your case you are calling `sendItems` of **DestinationVC**.

I am sorry for my bad explanation but I guess you would have get the basic idea.

Comment: Okay as you refer that "delegates has all the control that an object of class will have and working on behalf of Class". So why don't we go for objects in these type of scenarios?

Comment: And can you please explain me about this  - 'Where in a called instance can we go back to the class calling it? With an encapsulated class we can’t. There is no way to send that revised model back to the original controller without breaking encapsulation or MVC.'

Comment: No you cant access encapsulated class or I would prefer to say method.. Even not with your object or instance of Class..

Comment: Can you please make your point a bit clear framing code above as an example?